# Getting term description in single post template

Tags: templates, terms

I have custom posts called 'esitykset' and it has custom taxonomy 'tapahtumat'. Now I have been trying to get the description on one of the term in 'tapahtumat' taxonomy and i have no idea why it is not showing up. I have searching everywhere possible but couldn't find the solutions. Please help. My sode in the single-esitykset.php is below

```
<h2><?php the_terms( $post->ID, 'tapahtumat');
        echo '<p>' . term_description( $post->ID, 'tapahtumat' ) . '</p>';
    ?>
</h2>
```

What is wrong with this code. Please help.

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/term_description uses the `term_ID`

Comment: @Michael you should post that comment as answer.

Comment: @Micheal I tried 'term_description( term_ID, 'tapahtumat' )' but it is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, you are looking for this

```
//to get all the terms for current post -
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'tapahtumat' );

//get description of each term
foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
  echo term_description( $term->term_id, 'tapahtumat' );
}
```